# Nodejs server is blocking by request async

Tags: node.js

I have a Nodejs server, I load a list with long d3.js calculation first that I return to client and after that, load another long list to prevision that the client will get that. 
I have set the function who do this to `async` but it blocked the server on it until it finish.

So the question is: How I create a function who don't totally block the server ? (Like a Thread in Java)

Code:

```
// Load nested data for id client
async function loadNestedData(body) {
    table[body.id] = {};
    table[body.id] = manager.getLongData(LongDataWithLongName);
}
app.post('/api/dynamic/', (req, res) => {
    let body = req.body;
    var nested_data = manager.getLongData(LongDataWithLongName);
    res.json(nested_data);
    loadNestedData(body);
});

app.get('/api/dynamic/id/:id?', (req, res) => {
    // If nested data have finish to load
    if (manager.getLongData(LongDataWithLongName)[req.params.id]!==undefined)
        res.json(manager.getLongData(LongDataWithLongName)[req.params.id]);
    else
        res.json("wait");
});
```

Comment: We’ve got to have some code to get a better idea of what’s going on.

Comment: The problem is specific to your code which wasn't posted. The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: And `cache` is what exactly? Which module (I'm assuming) did you use? Do you even invoke the `loadNestedData` function?

Comment: I have replace long variable with an example, cache is a module that allow us to store data in cache for server